# Как удалить уже загруженные бандлы Unity?

Tags: android, unity3d, loading

В случае, если бандл был загружен ранее, при попытке повторной загрузки (например в процессе загрузки произошла ошибка и я хочу выполнить повторную), я получаю ошибку:  The AssetBundle can't be loaded because another AssetBundle with same files is already loaded.

`Caching.ClearCache();` - проблему не решает. Как я понял, он удаляет содержимое каталога cache, но бандлы сохраняются в files/UnityCache.

Как можно решить эту проблему? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно было предварительно выгрузить бандлы: `AssetBundle.Unload(true);`
Проблема решена.

Comment: Тогда закройте свой вопрос) чтобы он не висел, как новый без принятых ответов